# javascript promise all array of values passed as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, promise

Given the following array of values:

```
var sportList = ['football', 'volleyball'];
```

i want to run a query on mongo database using each of these values:

```
function myFunc(sport, callback) {
  mongoDB.sports.find({'name': sport}, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error)
    } else {
        callback(null, result)
    }
  })
}
```

so i build my promises like:

```
var promises = sportList.map(function(val){
    return myFunc(val);
});
```

and then trying to run all in a promise all chain:

```
Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log('log results: ', result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

but this is not working, because it is complaining that the `callback` is undefined, how can i fix this up correctly?

Comment: In order to use `Promise.all`, you should actually have an array of promises. `myFunc` doesn't return anything, so at the moment you have an array of `undefined` values. You have to make it return a promise.

Comment: `callback` is undefined — you're not passing a value to it. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: also, promises will be an array of `undefined` if you do supply a callback ... Promise.all ideally should be supplied an array of Promises ... `myFunc` has nothing to do with Promises

Comment: try changing myFunc to `const myFunc = sport => new Promise((resolve, reject) => mongoDB.sports.find({'name': sport}, (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result)));`

Comment: or, if using latest nodejs (I'm assuming nodejs here)... add `const myFuncAsync = utils.promisify(myFunc)` to your code and use `var promises = sportList.map(myFuncAsync)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are calling the `myFunc` method without supplying the `callback` parameter.

A solution would be to replace the `myFunc` function with the below. This function will return a new `Promise`. I haven't tested the below code but it should work.

```
function myFunc(sport) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoDB.sports.find({'name': sport}, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
          reject(error);
      } else {
          resolve(result);
      }
    })
  }));
}
```